# In Sensu server I am facing issue when I want to use graphite

Tags: sensu

In Sensu server logs :- level":"fatal","message":"handler socket must be a hash","object":{"type":"tcp","host":"127.0.0.1","port":2003,"name":"graphite_tcp"}}

Comment: Post some configuration data, there's nowhere near enough information here to determine what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is invalid

Right format is:

```
{
   "type": "tcp",
   "host": "127.0.0.1",
   "port": 2003,
   "name": "graphite_tcp"
}
```